# Password Field in Microsoft Edge is blank despite having a value attribute

Tags: html, forms, browser, microsoft-edge

I have a password field

```
<input type="password" name="Password" id="Password" value="PASSWORD" tip="" autocomplete="off">
```

When I load the page in any other browser I see the password field with the ****** filled in, however, when I load the page in MS Edge the field is blank, and when I submit the form, no value is passed.

Is this a bug, or is there something else I am missing?

Comment: Is there more than one password field in the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's more than one field it could be related to this: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/804869/ie11-multiple-password-fields-on-https-page

Comment: That's gotta be it, thank you. It was hard to search for, everything about password fields seemed to be about autocomplete bugs.